# How to pass targets configuration values to dependency targets buildphase run script?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have multiple targets in my projects, and they all have different Info.plist files, e.g.,

- MyTarget1 (Target1-Info.plist)
- MyTarget2 (MyTarget2-Info.plist)
- MyTarget3 (Info-T3.plist)

And all Targets are "sharing" one Settings.bundle/Root.plist file in the project.

Every time I build a target, I want to parse a value from the target's Info.plist file and write it into Settings.bundle so I wouldn't have to do it manually.

What I tried: to make Run Scripts in the Build Phases of the targets and do the writing there, but what I saw was that the value was written into the Settings.bundle *after* the build process itself. So in order to see the value under the Settings, I have to build it twice and this is not a very good solution, I think.

So I tried to make a new Target (e.g., named "PRE") and made it a dependency for the three targets I had and run the script there. Now the question is, how can I pass the Target info into the PRE target, so it would know what the name of the Targets Info.plist file is, or what macros should I use to get access to the each target's plist?

Comment: Are you writing to a file in the sources directory or in the Target directory?  I've had much better luck doing the latter, although it requires being careful with the symbols used in the script to describe the path.